# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in jquery-1.9.1.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error, uncaught-exception

I get this error:
First error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } => jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3
Now the error says: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } =>fase1_manual.php?lic=1:15

But when i look where they say, I don't see any error...

On my page, the only jquery i use is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#mydate').click(function() {
            $('#mydate').datebox('open');
        });
    });
</script>
```

And i use a jQuery Mobile datebox.

Can't seem to see what's wrong, makes my page freeze from time to time, when submitting my form.
Thanks to anyone that can help!

Entire page:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("connections.php");

$nameErr = $fnameErr = $bdErr = "";
$name = $fname = $bday = "";
if (isset($_GET["submit"]) && !empty($_GET['submit'])) 
{
    if (empty($_GET["patname"])) {
        $nameErr = "Mag niet leeg zijn";
    }
    else {
        $name = cleanValue($_GET["patname"]);
        if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z -]+$/",$name))
        {
            $nameErr ="";
        }
        else 
        {
            $nameErr = "Moet enkel uit letters bestaan";
        }
    }

    if (empty($_GET["patfname"])) {
        $fnameErr = "Mag niet leeg zijn";
    }
    else {
        $fname = cleanValue($_GET["patfname"]);
        if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z -]+$/",$fname))
        {
            $fnameErr="";
        }
        else
        {
            $fnameErr = "Moet enkel uit letters bestaan";
        }
    }
    if (empty($_GET["birthdate"])) {
        $bdErr = "Mag niet leeg zijn";
    }
    else {
        $bday = cleanValue($_GET["birthdate"]);
        $bdErr="";
    }

    if ( $fnameErr === '' &&  $nameErr === '' && $bdErr === '') {
        $destination_url = "fase1.php?patfname=$fname&patname=$name&birthdate=$bday&lic=".$_SESSION['lic_key'];
        header("Location:$destination_url");
        exit();
    }
}

include("header.php");
?>

<div id="div-header-fullwidth">
    <p>MediQueue Registratie APP: FASE 1 - Zelfregistratie</p>
</div>
<div id="div-content-fullwidth">
    <div id="div-container">
        <div id="div-logo">
            <p>
                <img src="http://mediqueue.newworld02.be/iris/registration/img/logo.png" width="129" height="158" id="logo" alt="logo" />
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="div-form">
            <form id="test" method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label for="patfname" class="ui-input-text">Voornaam:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="patfname" name="patfname" value="<?=$fname?>"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="error">
                            <?php echo $fnameErr;?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label for="patname" class="ui-input-text">Achternaam:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="patname" name="patname" value="<?=$name?>"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="error">
                            <?php echo $nameErr;?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label for="mydate" class="ui-input-text">Geboortedatum:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input name="birthdate" id="mydate" value="<?=$bday?>" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "datebox", "beforeToday": true, "minYear": 1900, "overrideDateFieldOrder": ["d","m","y"], "overrideDateFormat": "%Y-%m-%d", "lockInput": true, "centerHoriz": true}' readonly="readonly"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="error">
                            <?php echo $bdErr;?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Registreer" data-theme="a"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#mydate').click(function() {
            $('#mydate').datebox('open');
        });
    });
</script>
<?
include("footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: If you don't take the care to indent your code, I'll won't find the bugs. And probably you neither. A code made without care is always buggy.

Comment: where is your jquery import for the actual library?

Comment: Your code is OK. Try to change your jQuery library.

Comment: My code was indented, but pasting it here it came out wrong. I tried to indent it here as good as i could. I also added the linked libraries..

Comment: Why are you including all libraries twice?

Comment: Which ones are added twice? they are all different libraries for all I know

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>` same...

Comment: Ok, i deleted the .min ones, but the problem persists.. I also changed the jQuery library to the latest one, but did not help

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>` same too, keep .min, they smaller..

Comment: Trying that as we speak, but that did not help, don't have any doubles now. I edited it in my post..

Comment: check  <input name="birthdate" id="mydate" value="<?=$bday?>" 
                                                             data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "datebox", 
                                                                "beforeToday": true, "minYear": 1900, 
                                                             "overrideDateFieldOrder": ["d","m","y"],
                                                                "overrideDateFormat": "%Y-%m-%d", "lockInput": true, 
   "centerHoriz": true}' readonly="readonly"/>

Comment: @Yogesh: don't really see what's wrong

Comment: comment that input html data control and check whether it works or not

Comment: it still works.. after submitting normally the page should redirect to another one, and it's there that something is fishy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it was a bug in jQuery Mobile, we decided to change everything to bootstrap, so only css-wise things changed, javascript/php/html stayed the same and the bug dissapeared.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your javascript code in jslint http://www.jslint.com/ and you will find the catch.

If you still face the issue, try using google jquery from link https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide 
to make sure that problem with jquery only.

If it works fine, then you need to reload jquery again, it may be the problem that jquery file was not downloaded correctly.

Comment: My code passes jslint except a few warnings on whitespaces. Jquery library does not pass jslint at all, probably normal with all the code in it, but why would a jquery library give a syntax error, it's too weird..